# Passing reference to the end of an array from C# to C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++

I'm writing a C# app that uses [this C++ library](https://github.com/rygorous/ryg_rans).
I managed to compile it to a DLL that can be called from C# code and written a simple wrapper that reflect DLL's functions.
Now I have a problem, because according to example I use (will be pasted below) I need to pass pointer to the end of the array to this method:

```
static inline void Rans64EncPutSymbol(Rans64State* r, uint32_t** pptr, Rans64EncSymbol const* sym, uint32_t scale_bits)
```

In my wrapper it looks like that:

```
[DllImport(DllPath, EntryPoint = "Rans64EncPutSymbol")]
public static extern void Rans64EncPutSymbol(ref Rans64State r, ref uint pptr, ref Rans64EncSymbol sym, uint scaleBits = DEFAULT_SCALE_BITS);
```

My example in C++ is using it like that:

```
uint32_t* out_buf = new uint32_t[out_max_elems];
uint32_t* out_end = out_buf + out_max_elems;


Rans64State rans;
Rans64EncInit(&rans);

uint32_t* ptr = out_end; // *end* of output buffer
for (size_t i = in_size; i > 0; i--) { // NB: working in reverse!
    int s = in_bytes[i - 1];
    Rans64EncPutSymbol(&rans, &ptr, &esyms[s], prob_bits);
}
Rans64EncFlush(&rans, &ptr);
rans_begin = ptr;
```

My code looks like this:

```
uint[] outputBuffer = new uint[OUT_MAX_ELEMS];
uint[] outputEnd = outputBuffer.Length > 0 ? outputBuffer : null;

Rans64State ransState = new Rans64State();
RansWrapper.Rans64EncInit(ref ransState);
//Not sure how to pass this pointer
for(int i = input.Length; i > 0; i--) {
    int s = input[i - 1];
    RansWrapper.Rans64EncPutSymbol(ref ransState, ref outputBuffer[outputBuffer.Length - 1], ref esyms[s]);
}
```

I've been reading about Marshal.AllocHGlobal() [because t was suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607441/passing-a-pointer-to-an-array-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll) but it's seems to not be working.

Comment: `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` is your answer, it returns an IntPtr to the beginning of the array, you then need to increment it by the size of the buffer to have a pointer to the end.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I need to provide uint and whenever I'm trying to do this using Marshal.AllocHGlobal() I'm stuck at type mismatch problem. var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((nint)outputBuffer[0]); gives me an error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ref nint' to 'ref uint' And how should I add my array size to phis pointer? += Array.Length? or += Array.Length*sizeof(uint)?

Comment: `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` is used to allocate a buffer, it takes the size of the buffer in bytes, it returns an `IntPtr` which is pretty much a `void*`, you need to increment it by `Array.Length*sizeof(uint)`, the buffer has no idea it is holding `uint`, you have to copy the data into and out of it.

Comment: If you're okay with using unsafe code, you can probably just pin your array with a `fixed` statement and then pass the pointer you want.